# Trying to target a class in my css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to target a class in my css to move along the side so its looks like a side navigation. I cant seem to target it, i am testing it with border and moving it, but cant seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated.

here is the html

```
<div class="sidebarContainer">
<div id="sidebar" class="tabbed-sidebar">
    <!-- The tabs -->
    <ul class="sidebar-tabs">
        <li id="t1" class="sidebar-tab t1"><a class="sidebar-tab t1" title="Tab 1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li id="t2" class="sidebar-tab t2"><a class="sidebar-tab t2" title="Tab 2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li id="t3" class="sidebar-tab t3"><a class="sidebar-tab t3" title="Tab 3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li id="t4" class="sidebar-tab t4"><a class="sidebar-tab t4" title="Tab 4">Tab 4</a></li>
        </ul>
            <!-- tab 1 -->
            <div class="sidebar-tab-content sidebar-tab-content-t1"> <--This is what i am trying to target to go along the side of.... the sidebar-tabs                    
                <ul>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

  <!-- tab 2 -->
  <div class="sidebar-tab-content sidebar-tab-content-t2">
      <p>what sup.</p>
  </div>
```

here is the css

```
#sidebar >  .sidebar-tab-content sidebar-tab-content-t1 ul {
    position:relative;
    border:5px solid red;
    left:200px;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `.` on `.sidebar-tab-content-t1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
#sidebar >  .sidebar-tab-content sidebar-tab-content-t1 ul {
```

This assumes `.sidebar-tab-content` is a direct child of `#sidebar` (because of the `>`) which is not the case, and also that `sidebar-tab-content-t1` is a tag (instead of a class on the same element because it lacks `.`) and descendant of `.sidebar-tab-content` which is also incorrect, so try changing your selector to:

```
#sidebar .sidebar-tab-content.sidebar-tab-content-t1 ul {
```

Or:

```
#sidebar .sidebar-tab-content.sidebar-tab-content-t1 > ul {
```

Comment: Great thank you so much. lots to learn still. didnt know a space in my class is affecting it

Comment: @user2512393 I'm glad it helped, and don't worry just keep practicing and everything will be easier eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `>` next to #sidebar.  That indicates that sidebar-tab-content is the first child under the sidebar div.  Remove that and you should be good

Comment: `>` does not mean `:first-child` or `:nth-child(1)`. `>` is a child selector, which selects all `.sidebar-tap-content` that a direct child of `#sidebar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#sidebar  div.sidebar-tab-content ul {

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove space in class and replace it with a dash so that it now looks like this then do the same in your css

```
class="sidebar-tab-content-sidebar-tab-content-t1"
```

Comment: WTF? His classes are fine, the selector is not.